# Validate li selects

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I have a form using Janko At Warpseeds Form to Wizard Plugin alongside the [ImagePicker plugin](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) and I would like to make sure all the images are selected before being able to click Next.

I am currently using Bassassistance validation plugin.

Does anyone have any idea how I could implement this?

JSFiddle showing current working code and all javascript here http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkxy/

```
    $(function () {
       jQuery(function($){
            var $signupForm = $( '#multipage' );
 $signupForm.formToWizard({
                submitButton: 'SaveAccount',
                showProgress: true, //default value for showProgress is also true
                nextBtnName: 'Forward >>',
                prevBtnName: '<< Previous',
                showStepNo: false,
                validateBeforeNext: function() {
                    var selectedCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible .selected').length;
    var totalCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible').length;

    if(selectedCount != totalCount) {
        alert('please select an image per selection');
    }
                }
            });
});

    $("select.image-picker").imagepicker({
        hide_select: true,
        show_label: true,
    });
    $("select.image-picker.show-labels").imagepicker({
        hide_select: true,
        show_label: true,
    });

    var container = $("select.image-picker.masonry").next("ul.thumbnails");
    container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        container.masonry({
            itemSelector: "li",
        });
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I submitted too quickly - thanks have edited it now.

Comment: Yes I saved it but forgot to paste it in....sorry, have editeted it now.

Comment: What is the problem that you have encountered?

Comment: I can't validate the next button - all the images need to be selected before the user can proceed to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    //inside "next.onclick" handler
    var selectedCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible .selected').length;
    var totalCount = $('.thumbnails.image_picker_selector:visible').length;

    if(selectedCount != totalCount) {
        alert('please select an image per selection');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - however this seems to popup the alert on the page load, rather than when attempting to click next.

Comment: yes, you have to make the check inside the "next button" handler.
the formtowizard plugin allows you to define a validation callback function:
validateBeforeNext see: http://www.ifadey.com/2012/06/form-to-wizard-jquery-plugin/ (validation callback)

Comment: Sorry my bad - Yes I get the alert when clicking on the next button, however it still proceeds to the next step.

Comment: So I managed to use the new ValidateBeforeNext and it works great with your code, however the only thing is that it just doesnt go to the next step now if all the images are selected.  Nearly there, its just this last thing!  Any ideas?  Your help has been very useful.

Comment: I've updated the code in my original question with your code so you can see how I;ve done it.

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkxy/7/
works with a small workaround ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works great on the jsfiddle, however when I use this code in my page I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined on my console....any ideas why that would be?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the JQuery versions are different?

Comment: Yes I changed the version that the reverse of the handlers work (already had that code snipped). You either have to adjust that part or make some modifications on the wizard plugin or is that approach out of question?

Comment: Im using Wordpress so the version is 1.8.2, is there a simple way around that?

Comment: Your ogirinal code worked really well, it just stopped the form from being able to proceed to next http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkxy/3/

Comment: Ah right. Perfect, now you just have to add return true or false to make it fully working.